# Django test assertTemplateUsed with included templates

Tags: django, django-tests

I have a base.html which includes a lot of .html templates. While testing for the correct template, the test fails because the response lists all of the templates used as includes in base.html. But the one which is used is also in the list. Here my code and the error from the test:

```
response = self.client.get(reverse('ListAccounts'))
self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
self.assertTemplateUsed(response=response, template_name='/backstage/account/list_accounts.html')
```

The test message:

```
AssertionError: False is not true : Template '/backstage/account/list_accounts.html' was not a template used to render the response. Actual template(s) used: backstage/account/list_accounts.html, backstage/base.html, backstage/partials/header_mobile.html, backstage/partials/header_topbar.html, backstage/partials/header_topbar_menu.html, backstage/partials/header_topbar_search.html, backstage/partials/header_topbar_notifications.html, backstage/partials/header_topbar_quickactions.html, backstage/partials/header_topbar_cart.html, backstage/partials/header_topbar_language.html, backstage/partials/header_topbar_userbar.html, backstage/partials/aside_menu.html, backstage/partials/sub_header.html, backstage/partials/generalModal.html, backstage/partials/footer.html, backstage/partials/quick_panel.html, backstage/partials/filter_panel.html, toastrMessageAjax.html
```

How can I test this ?

Comment: It'd be good if you post your `views.py`, `urls.py` and also your templates, especially the `base.html`, otherwise it's very hard to see the big picture

Comment: its clear in the error, you have given `/backstage/account/list_accounts.html` while the path is `backstage/account/list_accounts.html`

Comment: can't see the forest for the trees, correct !!